# Mathematical equivalent of a one-dimensional array as seen in programming

Tags: terminology

Suppose some kind of structure to hold a (finite) number of elements is needed. The order of the elements matters and duplicate elements are allowed. When programming one would use a one-dimensional array for this.

What mathematical structure comes closest to such a one-dimensional array as seen in programming? I've seen both row and column vectors being used for this purpose, but it seems that a sequence would do as well. Is there any reason to choose one over the other or to choose an entirely other structure?

Comment: A function from a subset of $\mathbb N$ to some set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A vector is the wrong object to consider.  While vectors (in $\mathbb{R}^d$) can be represented as ordered lists, calling something a vector implies that it comes from a space with a great deal more structure.  Specifically, vectors can be added together, and can be scaled by field elements (in the case of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, you can multiply a vector by a real number).

A closer analogy would be a *sequence* (if your array has infinite length, or if you are willing to pad it by zero) or an [*$n$-tuple*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple) (if your arrays are all of the same length $n$).  Either of these objects may be thought of as a function from (a subset of) the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ to the appropriate set (e.g. the set of floating point numbers, the set of integers, the set of real numbers, etc).

For example, the array

```
 float array[5] = {3.14, 0.60309, 2.7183, 2, 1.618}
```

could be written as a $5$-tuple
$$ (3.14, 0.60309, 2.7183, 2.0, 1.612), $$
which can be thought of as a function $ a : \{0,1,2,3,4\} \to (\text{Set of Floats})$ defined by
$$
\begin{cases}
3.14 & \text{if $x=0$,} \\
0.60309 & \text{if $x=1$,} \\
2.7183 & \text{if $x=2$,} \\
2.0 & \text{if $x=3$, and} \\
1.612 & \text{if $x=4$.}
\end{cases}$$
That is (for example) $a(2) = 2.7182$.

As rschwieb noted in a comment below, this last way of looking at a tuple or array is likely the most relevant for software engineers:  one passes an index to the array, and gets back the value of the array element stored at that index.  This is equivalent to evaluating the function at that index.

Comment: So, the software engineer operates with the function almost all the time, only they know it is "indexing into the array."

Comment: @rschwieb That is a good point.